# Could not find gem 'bcrypt-ruby (= 3.2.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am going through Learn Web Development with Rails Michael Hartl.  I am currently on section 6.3.1. I went into my gem file and addd, gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.2.1'.

Whenever I save the file and run bundle install, I get this message:

Could not find gem 'bcrypt-ruby (= 3.2.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was completely my fault.

The correct gem is 3.1.2 not 3.2.1.